# What does 'screams' mean in this video?

Tags: word-meaning, slang

A fan [asked the youtuber a question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9vIQSSTnLY&ab_channel=MainlyFact), then the youtuber made up a story.

The question:

> What **screams** "I Have A Crush On You" ?

The story:

> When the girl turns her head to you, sees you're looking at her butt and gives you the "frick me" eyes.

What does the 'screams' mean here? It sounds like slang, but the explanation in *onlineslangdictionary* doesn't fit here.

Comment: *Slang* is uncountable, so "it sounds like slang", not "a slang".

Comment: Thanks! Never notice that. Question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What (behaviour or appearance) ***gives a clear signal*** that someone "has a crush on you" (is romantically attracted to you).

---

Note that this figurative use of ***scream*** is extremely colloquial. A more formal / literary alternative is...

> *[His manner **radiates**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his%20manner%20radiates%22) confidence / resignation / sadness...*

...so *in principle* you could write *Her manner radiated "I have a crush on you".*

Comment: Every little breeze seems to whisper 'Louise'...

Answer (score 1):

When something (a situation, something that you see, hear, understand, realise, etc) figuratively 'screams' *an idea* to you, that means it very strongly and forcibly suggests that idea to you (a literal scream is hard to ignore).

> The alarm bells, smoke and flames screamed 'Get out of the building,
> NOW'.

The writer is suggesting that when a girl looks at you, sees you are looking at her butt, and she gives you a 'frick me' look, that action of hers suggests to you very strongly that she has a crush on you.

> Scream (verb) (transitive or intransitive)
>
> to state something in a loud way that is difficult to ignore, or to be
> immediately obvious
>
> ‘Devil Dogs’, the headlines screamed.
>
> It was the kind of shirt that screamed vulgarity.
>
> It’s a badly written essay, and the grammatical mistakes just scream
> out at you.

[Scream (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/scream_1)

Comment: Note that many people may feel that the advice contained in the example text is sexist and not always reliable. Sounds like young teen boy stuff.